Unparallel pre-treatment trends in Synthetic Control Method
I'm running a synthetic control model using the R package Synth with crime data from 200 localities over 44 quarters (36 pre-treatment and 8 post-treatment). My model includes several socio-demographic variables (e.g., total population, mean age, male ratio, mean income) and total crimes as the outcome variable.
However, the trends of the treated and synthetic units are not parallel, which is unlike the near-perfect mimicry often seen in articles. This is how it looks like in my data:

My main question is: Is this good enough for a valid comparison? If not, how may I improve it?
For instance, should I consider using fewer control units in the donor pool, and if so, based on which criteria?
I should note that I tried using crime rate (per 1,000 residents) and also moving average of the crime rate (to try to "smoothen" the trend) but it didn't help.
Any advice would be appreciated.
Thanks!
Edit: here is a plot of total crime for the treatment unit (black) and donor pool units (white).


How many units are treated? Are you using aggregated (averages) or raw quarterly variables for the pre-treatment covariates and lags to construct the weights?

Also, could you add a plot showing the time series for total crime with the treated units highlighted and potential donors in light grey? All 220 in same plot, but no need for a legend or labels.

Hi @dimitriy, I added the plot you requested. I hope this is what you meant.
As for your first comment, I have only one treated unit. For all variables, I use just the count of crime for each quarter. Thanks!

Here are six suggestions that may help you secure a better pre-treatment fit. However, tighter is not always better since you may just be overfitting at the expense of your post-treatment validity, but I agree with you that the first graph does not look convincing. These suggestions are roughly in order of importance and ease of implementation.

Rescale the outcome and covariates you use to construct the weights to correct for differences in size between units. Instead of total crimes, use crimes per XK residents. Remove population since population per capita does not make sense, and your unit of interest is populous. Normalizing is unnecessary when the data variables do not scale with size (e.g., prices, unemployment rate, or pop density). The intuition for this is that you are trying to construct a weighted average of potential donors with weights that sum to 1 and are all $\ge 0$. Suppose your treated unit is a 400, and all your donors lie between 0 and 399. There are no weights that will work! You can see this issue plainly in the graph where you have ~2 potential donors consistently greater than your treated unit and ~190 always below during pre-treatment: this is not a lot to work with at the top. Scaling by pop can help you get a better fit. Ideally, you should see many donor units on either side of the treated unit (both outcome and Xs). If not, there could be other transformations that may work (time differences, growth rates, differences with respect to pre-intervention means), though these are often less credible when levels don't work. If the outcome looks good, but some Xs don't, try removing them from the specification unless they loom large in theory or previous literature.


Prune your potential donor pool in a systematic way. Counterintuitively, more is not always better here.


Remove any units that adopt interventions similar to the one under investigation during the study period.
Eliminate any units that may have suffered large idiosyncratic shocks to the outcome during the study period if such shocks would not have affected the outcome of the unit of interest in the absence of the intervention.
Restrict the donor pool to units with characteristics similar to the treated unit (crime, the Xs, and potentially also things like weather/culture/etc. that may not be used directly in your analysis as variables). In the German reunification paper, the authors restrict the donors to OECD countries. Alaska, Hawaii, and Puerto Rico can often be strange, in my experience.
Consider removing any potential donors that are affected by spillovers from treatment. Typically, these are adjacent but could also be connected culturally.
Once you have a smaller set, you can do a robustness check where you drop one donor, repeat the analysis without it, and hopefully, results remain stable. It would be concerning if your estimate depends on a single donor.


Consider aggregating your data from quarterly to annual (or perhaps half-years). Sometimes, seasonality makes units look dissimilar but goes away when you zoom out. For example, you might have a warm place where there is a consistent level of crime throughout the year and a cold place that has more in the summer and less in the winter. But yearly, they may have the same amount of crime and could become comparable if your intervention does not interact with climate. This is in the same spirit as the smoothing you attempted by averaging.

Consider aggregating the lags of the outcome and the covariates that you use in the weight estimation. Instead of using quarterly $Y_{1},
\dots, Y_{36}$, try going to half-year, annual, lustrums (5-year periods), decades, all the way up to totals/mean/median/quartiles for the entire pre-treatment period. If this is an important variable (like the outcome) with very heterogeneous trends across units, I would try the most disaggregated version you can. If it's less important or there is a lot of co-movement across units without many crossings, the averaging over the entire pre-treatment period would be acceptable. You can even mix durations here: more granular for the outcome and coarser for things that don't change over time, like latitude and longitude. Using more aggregated versions will generally select sparser donor groups (fewer control units with non-zero weights). Ideally, you want to show that the level of aggregation does not matter too much for the estimate. If seasonality is an important factor, you can average all the Q4s in a decade together, do the same for the other three quarters, and include these in the weight calculation.

Play around with the length of the pre-treatment period or exclude some periods. Sometimes, if you go too far back, there will be a structural break (like the fall of the USSR or changes in reporting or data collection). Cutting off the early era can help if you are focused on the latter period. Similarly, if local shocks hit some potential donors, don't use those periods when constructing the weights since they may cost you some otherwise excellent donors.

Interrogate your data quality. I understand that there have been some issues in transitioning UCR from SRS to NIBRS since 2021, where some police departments are not reporting their data or reporting incomplete numbers to the BJS. Ensure you don't have zeros instead of missings or any incompletes in your data (or patch this up somehow). There may have also been some other changes that are not apparent from the data. If you are working with victimization data, this is not a concern.


